# delayed job issue in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

My controller data_files_controller.rb

```
def upload_balances
  DataFile.load_balances(params)
end
```

My model data_file.rb

```
def self.load_balances(params)
  #  Pull the file out of the http request, write it to file system
  name =  params['Filename']
  directory = "public/uploads"
  errors_table_name = "snapshot_errors"
  upload_file = File.join(directory, name)
  File.open(upload_file, "wb") { |f| f.write(params['Filedata'].read) }
  # Remove the old data from the table
  Balance.destroy_all
  # ------ more code-----
end
```

It's working fine. Now i want to use delayed job with my controller to call my model action like ..
My controller data_files_controller.rb

```
def upload_balances
  DataFile.send_later(:load_balances,params)      
end
```

Is it possible?? What's the other way to do it? Is it create any problem?

With this send_later i am getting this error in column last_error in delayed_job table.

```
uninitialized stream
C:/cyncabc/app/models/data_file.rb:12:in `read'
C:/cyncabc/app/models/data_file.rb:12:in `load_balances'
C:/cyncabc/app/models/data_file.rb:12:in `open'
```

I am getting error on line

```
File.open(upload_file, "wb") { |f| f.write(params['Filedata'].read) }
```

while reading params['Filedata'].read.

how to check i am getting proper data in params['Filedata'] or not ?
Without send_later it's working fine... Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should check what's in the database.  Delayed Job must have strings, or ids internally when running it: most probably

params['Filedata']

contains something that is not revivable when the job runs later.

Comment: If user upload any csv file than first load_balance function will create that file in public/upload and write content in it from the original file. Than with faster csv it will enter the records from the file to database. But it's not storing anything params['Filedata'] or params['Filename'] in the database.

Answer (score 0):

using `send_later` should work fine. The other way is to define your own class that responds to `perform`, and call `Delayed::Job.enqueue YourClass.new`

Did you have errors somewhere?